# Select in JSP don't send value to java controller

Tags: java, jsp

I have an problem with select in my .JSP file:

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" name="poiCategory" id="poiCategory"
        data-size="10" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="-1">Brak</option>
    <c:forEach items="${categoryList}" var="category">
        <option value="${category.id}" data-tokens="${category.name}">${category.parent.parent.name}
            <b>&rarr;</b> ${category.parent.name}
            <b>&rarr;</b> ${category.name}
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

- Bootstrap 4.1
- Java Spring MVC

In controller:

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("poiCategory"));
```

return null...

Other inputs send parameters normally.

Can you help?

Comment: Is the `<select>` placed inside the `<form>`?

Comment: Yes, form with action and post method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using spring MVC `<form:select/>` instead

```
<form:select path="poiCategory">
   <form:option value="-1" label="Brak"/>
   <form:options items="${categoryList}" itemValue="name" itemLabel="category.parent.name"/>
</form:select>
```

This example might need some changing to fit your needs but I believe it should work.

To use this tag library you need to add the following directive to the top of your jsp page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `ModelAttribute` and `spring forms` to do your work.

Here is sample code in which user is selected from dropdown and it's value is received at backend.

In JSP :

```
<form:form action="someURL" modelAttribute="userform" method="POST">

    <form:select path="username">
        <form:option value="1"></form:option>
        <form:option value="2"></form:option>
        <form:option value="3"></form:option>
    </form:select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form:form>
```

In Controller :

```
public void getSelectedUser(@ModelAttribute UserProfile user) {
        System.out.println("in the select method " + user.getUsername()); // prints value 1/2/3
    }
```

Few things to take care of are : 
1: UserProfile is JAVA class which has "username" as it's field.

2: We should add "userform" as the object in the modelandview of jsp. 
   modelAndView.addObject("userform" , new UserProfile());

3: write path in the spring forms and assign a value to it which is also a field of passed class. ( in this case, it is "username" ).